# Spark code giving error

Tags: bigdata, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting error while running the below SPARK code that I have written. I am trying to find sum of all the vectors based on key. Each input line starts with key(integer) then 127 floating point numbers which is a single vector having 127 dimensions ie each line starts with a key and a vector.

---

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

class testing:
    def __str__(self):
        file_str = StringIO()
        for n in self.vector:
            file_str.write(str(n)) 
            file_str.write(" ")
        return file_str.getvalue()
    def __init__(self,txt="",initial=False):
        self.vector = [0.0]*128
        if len(txt)==0:
            return
        i=0
        for n in txt.split():
            if i<128:
                self.vector[i]=float(n)
                i = i+1
                continue
            self.filename=n
            break
def addVec(self,r):
    a = testing()
    for n in xrange(0,128):
        a.vector[n] = self.vector[n] + r.vector[n]
    return a

def InitializeAndReturnPair(string,first=False):
    vec = testing(string,first)
    return 1,vec


from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = (SparkConf()
         .setMaster("local")
         .setAppName("My app")
         .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

inp = sc.textFile("input.txt")
output = inp.map(lambda s: InitializeAndReturnPair(s,True)).cache()
output.saveAsTextFile("output")
print output.reduceByKey(lambda a,b : a).collect()
```

Example line in `input.txt`

> 6.0 156.0 26.0 3.0 1.0 0.0 2.0 1.0 15.0 113.0 53.0 139.0 156.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 156.0 29.0 1.0 38.0 59.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 28.0 4.0 2.0 9.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 9.0 83.0 13.0 1.0 0.0 9.0 42.0 7.0 41.0 71.0 74.0 123.0 35.0 17.0 7.0 2.0 156.0 27.0 6.0 33.0 11.0 2.0 0.0 11.0 35.0 4.0 2.0 4.0 1.0 3.0 2.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 19.0 45.0 17.0 47.0 2.0 2.0 7.0 59.0 90.0 15.0 11.0 156.0 14.0 1.0 4.0 9.0 11.0 2.0 29.0 35.0 6.0 5.0 9.0 4.0 2.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 5.0 25.0 14.0 27.0 2.0 0.0 2.0 86.0 48.0 10.0 6.0 156.0 23.0 1.0 2.0 21.0 6.0 0.0 3.0 31.0 10.0 4.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 2.0

Below is the error that I am getting. This error is coming from last line of the code ie `output.reduceByKey`

Error message - http://pastebin.com/0tqiiJQm

Not really sure how to approach this problem . I tried using a `MarshalSerializer` but its giving same issue .

**------------------------------Answer------------------------------------**

I got answer from [apache user list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Python-code-crashing-on-ReduceByKey-if-I-return-custom-class-object-td17317.html) for the same question. Basically the mapper/reducer that is run in the cluster doesnot have class definition and we have to pass the class by writing the class in a different module and attaching while configuring the SparkContext by using

```
sc.addPyFile(os.path( HOMEDirectory + "module.py"))
```

Thanks all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use numpy arrays which work well with spark.

```
import numpy as np

def row_map(text):
    split_text = text.split()
    # create numpy array from elements besides the first element 
    # which is the key
    return split_text(0), np.array([float(v) for v in split_text[1:]])

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = (SparkConf()
     .setMaster("local")
     .setAppName("My app")
     .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

inp = sc.textFile("input.txt")
output = inp.map(row_map).cache()
#Below line is throwing error
print output.reduceByKey(lambda a,b : np.add(a,b)).collect()
```

lot more concise and pythonic.

Comment: This solution is cool and working well . Can you suggest where I might be going wrong if I want to return custom class object instead of array - I am planning to return other objects along with this array.

Comment: The reason you are running into the issue is because the testing class isn't serializable. Look at the python docs for further info on how to fix that https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances

your other option is to create your classes after you have collected  the output eg:

    data = output.reduceByKey(lambda a,b : np.add(a,b)).collect()
    final_output = [testing(value) for value in data]
THis would only work if the size of data is small enough to be handled in a non parallelized fashion.

Comment: I have posted the same question in Apache spark users list and I got an answer on how to use custom class which I will add in the question itself for knowledge sharing .  I will accept your answer since it addresses the problem that I have faced to some extent